TEMPDB files not correct
On my SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition server, when I run
select * from sys.master_files

I see that tempdb has 8 data files and there are 8 data files in the folder.
However, when I run
select * from tempdb.sys.database_files

I only see 1 data file. Also, when I select the properties of tempdb, and look at the files, I see only 1 data file.
I can delete the 7 extra files, so they are not locked or in use by SQL Server.
When I restart the SQL Server service, all 8 data files appear and the whole thing repeats.
There are no startup scripts or SPs that run when the service starts.
What is going on?

The information about database files is stored in two places.

The master database holds instance-wide information in system tables underlying sys.master_files. When you access that view from a user database, you are shown data from master.
Each database holds a list of its own files exposed through the sys.database_files view.

It seems the two copies are out of sync. How that happened is something only you can investigate from your change control and other administrative records.
Look at the sys.master_files rows carefully. If the problematic rows have a non-null drop_lsn, you could try taking a log backup of master to allow the DMV to update. If you do that and restart, you may find the extra entries have gone.
Beyond that, there are other non-destructive things you can try using normal ALTER DATABASE commands (not SSMS).
For example, you could try adding the files that exist but are unknown to one copy of the metadata. You could also try removing them.
One or both of those might fail with an informative error message, giving you a clue how to proceed. You may need to restart between attempts to enable the server to pick up the new metadata. Also check the server's error log carefully for any interesting messages.
There are more extreme options, but you should start with those and proceed in a careful and logical manner.
